# ETH wallet issues

Tags: wallets, addresses, cpp-ethereum

I use Coinomi wallet and everything was ok untill I tried to add my wallet to another system like MEW and Metamask
I use same recovery phrase but I end up with different account with no money there. Yeah, I double-checked everything. Same phrase but different ETH address...

Any ideas what can I do to see the correct address at metamask or MEW or any other system?
Thanks!

Comment: Check this article in Coinomi help desk https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000016910.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but people will still find this page when searching this problem, so I'm answering anyway.

I had the same problem.  I found that the reason is that Coinomi's recovery phrase isn't compatible with other wallets.  The way to export from Coinomi is to find the private key of each coin that you want to export, and then import that key into the new wallet.  Here are [instructions for extracting your private key from Coinomi](https://forum.livepeer.org/t/import-your-coinomi-account-to-metamask/269).